# Is it possible to edit the thumbnail image of a Reel?

Tags: facebook, facebook-videos

I created a Reel and Facebook automatically created a thumbnail image from a frame in the video that is completely white.

I want to change the thumbnail image but can't find a way to do it.

How can I edit the thumbnail/preview image of a Facebook Reel?

Comment: You can't currently.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem today and just realized that using Facebook app on your phone instead of using website provided you a lot more options and flexibility.
Upload the Reel using Facebook app -> click Next -> tap on the Reel frame on the top left corner -> easily choose the thumbnail cut straight from the video or upload an image from the phone -> Done!

Comment: To be clear are you saying there is no way to edit it but you can customize it on the first upload?